# Angular не видит стили bootstrap

Tags: angular, scss

Я пытаюсь скопировать форму в свой проект вместе с используемыми стилями

Элемент формы

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="small mb-1" for="inputEmailAddress">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputEmailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address" />
</div>
```

файл styles.scss исходного проекта

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

файл styles.scss в моем проекте

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

в обоих проектах стили находятся в этой папке

```
'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Но когда я запускаю на выполнение, моя форма имеет другой вид. В отладчике видно, что подгружаются другие стили.

Вот мои стили в отладчике

[image: main project]

А это стили в исходном проекте

[image: src project]

Comment: А пробовали добавлять bootstrap в angular.json?

Comment: Нет, а куда его добавлять надо? Я думал об этом, но в исходном проекте в angular.json нет упоминаний о bootstrap и все работает. Почему то он импортит все файлы в style.css, а у меня нет. Если надо могу выложить исходный angular.json

Comment: В angular.json есть раздел styles, в который подключаются глобальные стили. Можно посмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project

Comment: Попробовал сделать как вы говорите, стало еще хуже у меня совсем стили полетели. И в той ссылке, что вы прислали, есть и тот вариант от mahatmanich, который я использую,  В файл style.scss @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";